# PointerWheelChanged not fired when use touchpad in ListView with WinUI3

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I use winUI3 to build my app and use `PointerWheelChanged` event in ListView to capture mouse wheel but it only works with mouse device but not with touchpad.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is because touch pad is no longer firing `PointerWheelChanged` events.  Here is a quote from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerwheelchanged?view=winrt-22621):

> Starting with Windows 8.1, ScrollViewer uses an underlying
> manipulation logic that interprets track pad gestures as actions that
> the ScrollViewer responds to, and thus the gesture is considered
> handled by the control and the PointerWheelChanged event is not fired
> anymore.

Comment: so, is there a way if I want to catch that event? I need to override ScrollViewer?

Comment: The ``ListView`` should scroll when you do scroll touch gestures on touchpad. Do you just need an event fired? or you need the precise delta values of the scroll event?

Comment: I just need an event fired to add other behavior when scroll up or down in ListView